# Create an animated GIF file without PIL or other python add ons

Tags: python, image, animation, save, gif

So I'm trying to write a program that creates a short animated GIF of red cube bouncing from left to right. I get stuck, however, when it comes to saving the images to a GIF file, and I've searched everywhere but I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this without using PIL or some other add on. (The program is for a class and we cannot use any such add ons)

The following is my code as of now..I've been playing around with it a lot so some of the code I previously used is commented out.

```
# BouncingCube.py

# This program is designed to produce an animated GIF displaying a red square bouncing back and forth between the left and right edges

import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import base64

root = Tk()

def fill_bg(image):
    r,g,b = (255,255,255)
    width = 110
    height = 110
    hexcode = "#%02x%02x%02x" % (r,g,b)
    horizontal_line = "{" + " ".join([hexcode]*width) + "}"
    image.put(" ".join([horizontal_line]*height))

def fill_box(image, color, pos):
    r,g,b = color
    width = 30
    height = 30
    x,y = pos
    hexcode = "#%02x%02x%02x" % (r,g,b)
    horizontal_line = "{" + " ".join([hexcode]*width) + "}"
    image.put(" ".join([horizontal_line]*height), (y,x))


i = 0
while i != 90:
    photo = PhotoImage(width=30, height=30)
    fill_bg(photo)
    fill_box(photo, (255,0,0), (40,i))

    #label = tkinter.Label(root, image=photo)
    #label.pack()
    i = i + 10
while i != 0:
    photo = PhotoImage(width=30, height=30)
    fill_bg(photo)
    fill_box(photo, (255,0,0), (40,i))

    #label = tkinter.Label(root, image=photo)
    #label.pack()
    i = i - 10

#root.mainloop()
```

Any help into the right direction would be greatly appreciated, even if it's a completely different method than the one I was attempting to use. Thanks much!!

Comment: Quickly Googling "gif file specification", the [document](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/GIF/spec-gif89a.txt) appears to be dozens of pages long. Are you 100% sure that you're expected to implement all of this yourself?

Comment: `tkinter` doesn't have native support for image sequence files (e.g. `.gif`). As far as I'm aware, this requires an external library like PIL.

Comment: I did find that it's possible to save a photo without PIL using something like `photo.write('cube.gif', format='gif')`. I replaced this line with my two sets of commented lines. This got me closer to my result, but instead of combining the gif images into an animation like expected, it just creates a final saved image of what should be the last frame in the animation...unfortunately not what I was looking for.

Comment: Yes, like I said, it doesn't have native support for that. `.gif` is one of the few filetypes it can handle, but only as static single images.